# Mediawiki database recovery

Tags: mysql, backup, mediawiki, restore

I had a small wiki I had hosted on a free host, but it seems it got spammed and the host took it down.  They passed me a `.sql` file which was 2GB large.  I am looking to set up another wiki, load the `.sql` into it and clean up the mess (or find the good stuff and copy it out).

I set up a new mediawiki, then I did the following:

```
mysql -u <user> -h mysql.domain.com -p<password> -e "drop database <dbname>;"
mysql -u <user> -h mysql.domain.com -p<password> -e "create database <dbname>;"
mysql -u <user> -h mysql.domain.com -p<password> <dbname> < file.sql
```

It takes a long time but I get no errors, then when I visit the mediawiki url I see:

```
A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.
```

Is this the wrong way to do this?  What is the easiest way I can do this correctly?

---

Edit:

Now seeing:

```
A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.

Query:
SELECT page_id,page_namespace,page_title,page_restrictions,page_counter,page_is_redirect,page_is_new,page_random,page_touched,page_latest,page_len,page_content_model FROM `page` WHERE page_namespace = '0' AND page_title = 'Main_Page' LIMIT 1
Function: WikiPage::pageData
Error: 1054 Unknown column 'page_content_model' in 'field list' (mysql.domain.com)
```

Comment: Did you update LocalSettings.php with the new MySQL host/user/password? Is it the same MediaWiki version? Did you run `php maintenance/update.php` on the new MediaWiki installation?

Comment: I set up the new wiki and updated the localsettings.php.  It ran, so I killed the database and imported the old 2Gb one.  I get a 403 error when I try to load update.php.  It has 644 permissions.  Should it be 755?  Also, the old mediawiki install has since gone, so I can't be sure on version.  Both were installed within the last couple of months.

Comment: The error message you quote is basically useless. Start by adding [`$wgShowSQLErrors = true;`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgShowSQLErrors) to your LocalSettings.php, so that you'll see what actually goes wrong. See also [How to debug SQL errors](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#SQL_errors) in the MediaWiki manual.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info.  I have a more detailed error and will look up the cause and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the SQL backup you have is from an older version of MediaWiki, and is missing the [`page.page_content_model`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_content_model) column (among others, likely).

To fix it, you will need to [run the database schema update script](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Run_the_update_script) ([`maintenance/update.php`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Update.php)) that comes with your version of MediaWiki.  You can either do this from the command line (recommended) or via the [web upgrader](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading#Web_browser) (if you don't have command-line access).

See the links above for more details, but basically, for a typical MediaWiki install with command-line access, you just need to `ssh` to your web host, `cd` to the MediaWiki root directory, and run:

```sh
php maintenance/update.php
```

You'll see a lot of output describing what the script is doing (mostly checking for missing database columns and adding them), but hopefully no errors.  If everything goes well, your wiki should now be ready to use.

Comment: Running now in command line.  Will tick this if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked beautifully!  Do you know if there is an easy way to delete all additions from a certain date onwards?

Comment: @James: "Easy" is a relative term, but you could do something like `DELETE FROM revision WHERE rev_timestamp >= 'YYYYMMDD'` and then repair the database using [these instructions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/mass-deletion-of-spam-revisions-in-mediawiki/45486#45486) (steps 6 and onwards).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I had around 50 pages I wanted to keep, I just copied and pasted.

Answer (score 3):

There are some extensions to [mass-delete pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_deletion_extensions) but no one can "delete all pages after a certain date". Depending of the typology of the pages you have to delete, you can use:

- [Extension:Nuke](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Nuke) distributed with MediaWiki (you only have to [register it in LocalSettings.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions)) to delete all pages from some users or IP, and then use the command-line script [`php maintenance/deleteArchivedRevisions.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php) to wipe archived versions from your database,
- [Extension:Extension:DeleteBatch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeleteBatch) if you can write a list of pages, and then use `php maintenance/deleteArchivedRevisions.php`,
- possibly other extensions in the category [Page deletion extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_deletion_extensions), but you should review the extension before using it, some seems to be less reliable than others, and keep your original database dump in case of problem.